# React Native with ARCGIS

Tags: react-native, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

How can I integrate ArcGIS JS API with React native? I am using expo for react-native. I don't want to use runtime SDK but a react-native library or API for the same purpose to build a react native widget and integrate with Mendix native.

My Android.manifest file has the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The error I get is as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijTjF.jpg)

Comment: There is documentation dedicated to this topic. Please have a look: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/react/

Comment: Hi I am looking for somehing with react native for native mobile apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArcGIS Runtime is Esri's SDK for native apps, whether you are doing native or React Native development. You should use ArcGIS Runtime for optimum performance and flexibility in your native app. ESRI does not provide a reusable map component for React Native, so you have to integrate it yourself. Here is an example / proof of concept showing how:
[Use ArcGIS Runtime in React Native](https://github.com/glazou/react-native-arcgis-sdk-demo)

If you want to use ArcGIS JS API in a native app, you have to render your map inside a WebView and create your own method of passing events and data between the map and the rest of your application logic. I would not recommend this method unless you have a very simple map and do not plan to have much interaction with it.

Comment: Hi Hrunar, I was indeed trying to run this POC but I get an error and the app crashes. The error is as follows:  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@40ec8528 -- permission denied for this window type 2003. These posts (here, here and here) all give the same answer. To add the following permission in the Manifest file.

    android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Solution that I have implemented but I am still getting the same error. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My Android.Manifest file has the following permissions<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Note I haven't made any alterations to the logic as of now. So this POC doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: How does ```react-native-argis-sdk-demo``` may work with managed Expo?